# Same interpolator for multiple animations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I want reference an Interpolator in xml because I have multiple animations,but I need all of them to use a same interpolator  because they all run at the same time,so I want to control it from one place.

Example.

slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/slide_anim_speed"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

As you can see, I have defined the duration as an integer in my integers.xml file. However, how can I achieve the same with the **android:interpolator**?

I want something like: **android:interpolator="@references/slide_interpolator"** and from there I want to reference the interpolator of my choice.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating the following file.

interpolator_slide.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bounceInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Now its very easy to change it, you simply change that line.
For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accelerateDecelerateInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

And I simply reference this file from the interpolator in the animation file.

Comment: you can also accept your own answer and receive a Badge for it